# Grothendieck problem

Tags: differential-equations, textbook-recommendation, grothendieck-construction

Could you suggest me a book or a link where I can find some information about the Grothendieck problem about differential equations?

The Grothendieck problem that I am reffering to is the following:

$$\alpha_n(x)y^{(n)}(x)+\dots +a_1 (x)y'(x)+a_0(x)y(x)=0, a_i \in \mathbb{Z}[x]\ \ \ \ (*)$$

We suppose that for almost each prime $p$, $(*)$, modulo $p$, has $n$ linearly independent solutions (powerseries in $\mathbb{F}_p((x))$, with field of constants $\mathbb{F}_p((x^p))$). Then $(*)$ has $n$ linearly independent solutions (powerseries in $\mathbb{C}((x))$ with field of constants $\mathbb{C}((x))$) and all are algebraic.

Comment: Are you talking about the Grothendieck-Katz conjecture?  Here is the  link to the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck%E2%80%93Katz_p-curvature_conjecture.

Comment: I added the statement of the problem I am reffering to. Is that the Grothendieck-Katz conjecture? @JasonStarr

Comment: I cannot say immediately that your formulation is the same as the standard formulation of the Grothendieck-Katz conjecture, but they look quite similar.

Comment: @JasonStarr Looks identical, actually...

Comment: What book would you suggest me to read to get more information about it?

Comment: The information on the wikipedia link is quite good. There are a few other references that I would add, notably Andre's book "G-functions and Geometry" and a couple of papers by D. and G. Chudnovsky, but they can all be found in the bibliography of, say, Chambert-Loir's paper linked to there. The list is then pretty much exhaustive, and it is up to you what to get out of it. (What kind of information do you look for? Do you for instance have the algebro-geometric background to follow Katz's *Inventiones* paper that contains the proof of the conjecture in the case of a Picard-Fuchs equation?)

Comment: D. and G. Chudnovsky have solved other cases by elementary methods of diophantine approximations (Pade approximants). Chambert-Loir's paper is probably the best place to start on this; then you may look into the original papers by the Chudnovskys.

Comment: I am reading the proof of Grothendieck's problem for differential equations of first order, but I am facing some difficulties to understand it... Could you take a look at it? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548963/proof-that-the-solutions-are-algebraic-functions